# Crystal Reports - Multiple Criteria for Same field

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Here's what I'm looking to get accomplished. I have a report that I'm currently running and attempting to get data off of 3 distinct variables however 2 of the criteria expressions are pulling from the same column. When I run my report I'm not able to get information. Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
{HSP_ACCT_DX_LIST.DX_ID} in [3534, 3535, 3536, 3537, 3538, 3539]
and {HSP_ACCT_DX_LIST.DX_ID} in [9147, 9159, 9154, 9157]
and {HSP_ACCT_CPT_CODES.CPT_CODE} in [22804, 22802, 22843, 22844, 22848]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DX_ID can't simultaneously be in two disjoint sets. It would have to be in one or the other:

```
{HSP_ACCT_DX_LIST.DX_ID} in [3534, 3535, 3536, 3537, 3538, 3539, 9147, 9159, 9154, 9157]
and {HSP_ACCT_CPT_CODES.CPT_CODE} in [22804, 22802, 22843, 22844, 22848]
```

EDIT:

If you need to check a single account for the presence of multiple Dx, then you'll have to add a copy of the HSP_ACCT_DX_LIST table to your report which would be joined to the hospital account in the same way. Your record selection formula would then look like:

```
{HSP_ACCT_DX_LIST_copy_1.DX_ID} in [3534, 3535, 3536, 3537, 3538, 3539]
and {HSP_ACCT_DX_LIST_copy_2.DX_ID} in [9147, 9159, 9154, 9157]
and {HSP_ACCT_CPT_CODES.CPT_CODE} in [22804, 22802, 22843, 22844, 22848]
```

Comment: See but that gives the option for a selection of any of the first or second DX_ID where I need them to contain one of both the first and the second set of DX_ID's on the account.

Comment: @user3754061 Then you will need to add a second copy of the HSP_ACCT_DX_LIST table to your report. See my edit.